# Android setText inside AsyncTask has no effect on the UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem related to `AsyncTask`. I want to change the text inside the `onPostExecute` method, but it doesn't work. I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Can somebody help me out please?

I don't understand why it work when I declare the `AsyncTask` as a nested class but it don't work when I declare it as a own class.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button = null;
    private Helper helper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.helper = new Helper(this, getLayoutInflater());


        this.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        this.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    new MyAsyncTask(helper).execute("");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Helper.java

```
public class Helper {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Helper(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        setContext(context);
        setInflater(inflater);
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public LayoutInflater getInflater() {
        return inflater;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }
}
```

MyAsyncTask.java

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Helper helper;

    public MyAsyncTask(Helper helper) {
        setHelper(helper);
    }

    public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        TextView t = (TextView) getHelper().getInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null).findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setText("" + s); //has no effect on the UI but the text was set????
        Toast.makeText(getHelper().getContext(), t.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getJSON("testside.com", 10000);
    }

    public Helper getHelper() {
        return helper;
    }

    public void setHelper(Helper helper) {
        this.helper = helper;
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing there... if you want to update a view on the UI thread, you should be on the UI thread. AsyncTasks are asynchronous, hence the name. They run on a different thread that does not have access to your UI thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code looks fine but it doesn't work because it take reference to TextView from new layou which you inflate.

You have two options:

1. In your helper store TextView which you want to change, you can make it optional if your helper looks something like this:

   ```
   public class Helper {

       private Context context;
       private LayoutInflater inflater;
       private TextView textView;

       ...       

       public void addTextView(TextView textView){
           this.texView = textView;
       }

       public TextView getTextView(){
           return textView;
       }
   }
   ```

   and then in your postExecute() call `TextView t = helper.getTextview()`.
2. Pass textView directly to your AsyncTask so it look like

   ```
   public MyAsyncTask(Helper helper, TextView t) {
       setHelper(helper);
       this.textView = t;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) its working now :) now i must see how i will take this with more as one TextView ;) Thank You :) and why i get a -1 rating? :o

Comment: when you declare `AsyncTask<String, String, String>` first argument is what you want input to asyncTask so you can declare it as  `AsyncTask<TextView, String, String>` and then in `doInBackground(TextView... params)` params is array of textviews you pass it in when you call `MyAsync.execute(texview1,textview2)`

Answer (score 0):

Utilize you AsyncTask outside of your main Class using separate files

```
class MyActivity{
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

Your AsyncTask lives as another class Extending AsyncTask

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
    public MyAsyncTask(Context appContext){

    }
}
```

Be sure to pass in your App's Context. You can only execute each instance of the task once.... but you can create and run a new instance when needed...

Wouldn't fly:

```
    class MyActivity{
        MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        myTask.execute();
        //DO OTHER STUFF
        myTask.execute();
    }
```

You would instead do each time needed:

`new MyAsyncTask().execute();`

Answer (score -1):

Your AsyncTask is executed on a background thread. To update your UI call,

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("Text");
    }

});
```

on an activity.